# Swift iOS Sprite Kit - Fade sprite from one color to another

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to fade a sprite from one color to another over x duration.
For example:
A yellow sprite fades to pink sprite in 4 seconds.

If possible, it needs to accept hex color codes, or something similar.

Thanks!
Toby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `colorizeWithColor` method on `SKAction` to create an `SKAction` that will change the colour of an `SKSpriteNode`. Here's an example:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

// Position and add the node to the scene...

let colorize = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 5.0)
node.runAction(colorize)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use https://gist.github.com/berikv/ecf1f79c5bc9921c47ef to allow UIColor to accept HEX codes.